# Laravel php artisan migrate not working

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, migrate, laravel-artisan

When I try to use 'php artisan migrate' in Laravel I get 2 errors:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is encrypted or is not a database

I created a storage/database.sqlite file before attempting the migration. I also edited the config/database.php, making the `default=sqlite`. I am using windows and have `sqlite3` installed.

Has anyone encountered this/know how to get past it?

Comment: Is there someone who can help with this? It is a massive stumbling block

Answer (score 10):

I had the same results, in my case the `/database/database.sqlite` file was not empty.

I deleted the contents reran 
`php artisan migrate` and the migration table was created successfully.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found a fix.I just abandoned sqlite and went back to mysql

Comment: i was having a new line in sqlite file, upon removing it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Running Laravel in Windows under the Powershell console I was getting the same errors as the original poster. The documentation reads *After creating a new SQLite database using a command such as  **touch database/database.sqlite**...* The Powershell equivalent of touch is typically **Out-File FILENAME**

```
PS D:\Learning\PHP-Laravel\database> out-file database.sqlite
PS D:\Learning\PHP-Laravel> php artisan migrate
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 26 file is not a database...
```

When creating my **database.sqlite** file I received these errors. I deleted the database and recreated it using the **New-Item** command and it worked properly

```
new-item -ItemType File -Name database.sqlite
PS D:\Learning\PHP-Laravel> php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody came here with the same error with manually created table in sqlite db - it could be the sqlite version mismatch. I solved the same error by emptying db file and recreate the table with getConnection()->statement('CREATE TABLE

Answer (score -1):

check if your .sqlite file is empty and the is no indentation(no spaces)

Comment: this is more of a comment