# Cakephp, File is not a database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to shift my cakephp projects from Windows to MAC, every thing is working fine on windows on mac i am getting

> **Error:** SQLSTATE[HY000]: **General error:** 26 file is not a database

Need help. Thanks

Comment: Look to the this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693754/laravel-php-artisan-migrate-not-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel php artisan migrate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693754/laravel-php-artisan-migrate-not-working)